# Retrieve Requested Controller/Action from within Doctrine2 Subscriber in ZF2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have many entities which contain many different fields but all of which include: IP, Timestamp and 'Controller/Action'.  The associated forms provide fields for all of the entity attributes except those three.  I'd rather not provide hidden fields and instead populate these 3 fields after form submission.

That is why I created a Doctrine Subscriber (according to [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#onflush)) and am listening to the 'onPersist' event.  I have successfully set the IP and Timestamp fields and saved them to my database from within the subscriber.  From within the requested controller, I can just do `$this->params('controller');` or `$this->params('action');` to get what I need. However I'm having some trouble retrieving the requested Controller/Action from within the subscriber.

I've tried implementing `Zend\Mvc\InjectApplicationEventInterface` according to [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.mvc-event.html) on both the subscriber and the subscriber's factory, but I end up just getting an empty instance of it, rather than the actual instance containing what I need.  I also tried dumping the contents of the various service managers (IE: ControllerLoader, ControllerPluginManager and ViewHelperManager) but didn't see any instance of 'Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent'

I have a hunch what I need is obtainable via one of the service managers.  What should I look into in order to figure out how to retrieve the existing instance of `Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent`?  Also, I'm assuming it would be best to retrieve it from within the Factory for my subscriber, if that is not the best approach, please correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a factory for your Doctrine subscriber and inject the `MvcEvent` from there. You can retrieve it from the `Application` object which is shared throughout the application lifetime.

**Config**

```
'doctrine' => [
    'eventmanager' => [
        'orm_default' => [
            'subscribers' => [
                'MyModule\SomeListener',
             ]
         ]
     ]
]
```

**Factory**

```
class SomeListenerFactory
{
    public function __invoke($serviceLocator)
    {
        return new SomeListener(
            $serviceLocator->get('Application')->getMvcEvent()    
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I had the factory and the service locator, just didn't know how to get the MvcEvent with it.  I also didn't realize there was a master Application object which will come in handy in the future.